# Display the result of a button from chlid component in parent component - Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, components, parent-child

I have a button in the chlid component which has a form, on click of the button, it adds in DB and gives out an alert. I want to display the alert in the parent component screen which shows the list of data in DB.

HTML:

```
<button class="pt-primary adconfig-button" *ngIf="!isEditMode" [disabled]="!testSuccessful" (click)="storeNewConnection()">Add Configuration</button>
```

TS:

```
        this.adService.addAdConfiguration(this.adConfigurationObj, this.isEditMode).subscribe((response) => {
            const msg: string = response.Status === ResultStatus.Success ? this.alerts.push(
                {
                    msg: 'Configuration added successfully!',
                    type: 'success',
                    timeout: 3000
                }) : response.Details;
        });
    }

        this.router.navigate(['/configuration/groups-permissions'], { state: { isAdConfig: true } });
```

I want to route to this path (parent component) and display the alert there.

How can accomplish it?

Answer (score 0):

1. The routing must be inside the subscription callback block to ensure it gets executed after the asynchronous call `this.adService.addAdConfiguration()` has responded.
2. There are multiple ways to pass data using Angular Router. The following shows leveraging optional parameters.

**Sender component**

```js
this.adService.addAdConfiguration(this.adConfigurationObj, this.isEditMode).subscribe((response) => {
  const msg: string = response.Status === ResultStatus.Success 
    ? this.alerts.push({
        msg: 'Configuration added successfully!',
        type: 'success',
        timeout: 3000
      }) 
    : response.Details;

    this.router.navigate(
      [
        '/configuration/groups-permissions',
        { message: JSON.stringify(msg) }
      ], 
      { state: { isAdConfig: true } }
    );
});
```

**Recipient component**

```js
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
  message: any;

  constructor(private _actRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.message = JSON.parse(this._actRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get(message));
  }
}
```

**Edit**: Typo `ActivateRoute` -> `ActivatedRoute`

Comment: what is _actRoute here?

Comment: Parameter property `private _actRoute: ActivatedRoute`. There was a typo in the original post. It said `ActivateRoute` instead of `ActivatedRoute`. I've modified the answer.

Comment: could also simply call it `activatedRoute` the prefix/abbreviation is purely an opinionated way of displaying the value from the constructor.

The general idea is to apply the message to the URL as a parameter and the on the parent parse the message from the URL to display it.